# C++ assignment operator and overloading

Tags: c++

I was wondering why the following code is being compiled successfully.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class Integer{
private:
    int i;
public:
    Integer(int value):i(value){}
    // unary or binary
    const Integer operator+(const Integer& rv){
        cout << "operator+"<< endl;
        return Integer(i + rv.i);
    }
    // Binary Operator
    Integer& operator+=(const Integer& rv){
        cout << "operator+=" << endl;
        i += rv.i;
        return *this;
    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& lv){
        lv << i;
        return lv;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& lv, Integer& rv);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& lv,Integer& rv){
    return lv << rv.i;
}

int main(){
    cout << "using operator overloading"<< endl;

    Integer c(0), a(4), b(5);
    Integer d = 8;
    c = a + b;
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << d << endl;
}
```

I dont understand why d = 8 is possible. d is a user defined type. I did not overloaded the assignment oeprator for the Integer class. Is there a default overloaded operator?

Comment: This site describes explicit/non-explicit constructors quite well: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not declared the `Integer` constructor `explicit`, so it acts as an implicit conversion from `int` to `Integer`.

If you declare your constructor

```
explicit Integer(int value);
```

the compiler fires the error:

> error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘Integer’ requested

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor defines conversion from int to Integer

```
Integer(int value):i(value){}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I dont understand why d = 8 is possible. d is a user defined type.

Just instrument your code a little more and also trace the ctor calls.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class Integer{
private:
    int i;
public:
    Integer(int value):i(value){
        cout << "Integer(int) called with " << value << endl; 
    }
    // unary or binary
    const Integer operator+(const Integer& rv){
        cout << "operator+"<< endl;
        return Integer(i + rv.i);
    }
    // Binary Operator
    Integer& operator+=(const Integer& rv){
        cout << "operator+=" << endl;
        i += rv.i;
        return *this;
    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& lv){
        lv << i;
        return lv;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& lv, Integer& rv);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& lv,Integer& rv){
    return lv << rv.i;
}

int main(){
    Integer d = 8;
     cout << d << endl;
}
```

output:

```
Integer(int) called with 8
8
```

[**live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc4e108f9a64cef2) at Coliru's

The presumed assignment of the immediate 8 in fact causes the non-[explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) `Integer(int)` ctor to be called with 8 as its argument.